# project comparison?

Tags: php, recursion, directory, diff

I have a project on my localhost that is working, however on the production server it is falling over.

What I want to do is download the project off the server, and do a comparison over the two project directories to find out if anything is different.

Are there any programs out there that can do a diff on entire directories recursive?

I dont mind if it just tells me what files are different and I can do a manual diff on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) for such comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Kdiff3 like already mentioned is excellent, but if you just want a list of files with differences you can run

```
diff -r -q /localhost/project/dir /downloaded/server/project
```

Answer (score 0):

why not upload the local version or download he remote version, usually this is not a file issue, its a server set-up issue, your local set-up will probably not match your remote one , especially if its a hosted account and\or 2 different os's